# I am trying to access the dictionary I made so that the command only runs if the user's ID is listed in the dictionary

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to access the dictionary I made so that the command only runs if the user's ID is listed in the dictionary

This is what I have come up with so far but it keeps on failing:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

dict = {'rand ID 1':'rand ID 2', 'rand ID 3':'rand ID 4'} 

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.lower().startswith('.test'):
    if message.author.id == "dict":
      embed1 = discord.Embed(title='Hello World!')
      await message.channel.send(embed=embed1)
```

Comment: Would this not be better suited to a list? Or is there a specific relation between IDs 1 and 2, as well as 3 and 4?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the `values()` method and search if it contains the `message.author.id`- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary

I notice that your dictionary does not have the expected key,values

```
# dictionary with integer keys
my_dict = {1: 'apple', 2: 'ball'}

# dictionary with mixed keys
my_dict = {'name': 'John', 1: [2, 4, 3]}

# using dict()
my_dict = dict({1:'apple', 2:'ball'})
```

It actually looks like a regular array/list, that you can iterate/or check that it contains the given element `message.author.id`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `set` to store the ids.

`whitelisted_ids = {'rand ID 1', 'rand ID 2', 'rand ID 3', 'rand ID 4'}`

---

Also, you can use a predicate for extract this behavior from the command itself.

```py
whitelisted_ids = {'rand ID 1', 'rand ID 2', 'rand ID 3', 'rand ID 4'}
# Might be in capital if constant


class NotWithinWhitelist(commands.CheckFailure):
  pass


def is_within_whitelist():
  async def predicate(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id not in whitelisted_ids:
      raise NotWithinWhitelist("You are not whitelisted for that command")

    return True

  return commands.check(predicate)


@client.command()
@is_within_whitelist
async def test(ctx):
    test_embed = discord.Embed(title='Hello World!')
    await message.channel.send(embed=test_embed)


@test.error
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.NotWithinWhitelist):
        await ctx.send(str(error))
```